# Connection refused for in spring boot pod while running with Kubernetes "PSQLException: Connection to postgres-service:5432 refused."

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, kubernetes

PSQLException: Connection to postgres-service:5432 refused - I'm running this on Minikube and docker desktop. Please help me, I'm doing POC so that I can implement it in my project. And I can login with localhost in the shell but not with service name(postgres-service)

```
psql -h localhost -U admin123 -p 5432 FSD_DB //working
psql -h postgres-service -U admin123 -p 5432 FSD_DB // connection refused
```

ConfigMap yml with postgres URL as the name of Postgres service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: postgres-config
data:
  POSTGRESDB: FSD_DB
  POSTGRESUSER: admin123
  POSTGRESPASSWORD: admin123
  POSTGRESURL: postgres-service
```

Postgres Deployment and service yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: postgres
        image: postgres:latest
        imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
          name: postgres
        env:
        - name: POSTGRES_USER
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: postgres-config
              key: POSTGRESUSER
        - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: postgres-config
              key: POSTGRESPASSWORD
        - name: POSTGRES_DB
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: postgres-config
              key: POSTGRESDB
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: postgres
    tier: database
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5432
      targetPort: 5432
```

Spring boot deployment and service yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: abcbank-deployment
  labels:
    app: abcbank
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: abcbank
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: abcbank
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: abcbank
        image: abcbank:r1
        imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8084
        env:
        - name: POSTGRES_USER
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: postgres-config
              key: POSTGRESUSER
        - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: postgres-config
              key: POSTGRESPASSWORD
        - name: POSTGRES_DB
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: postgres-config
              key: POSTGRESDB
        - name: POSTGRES_HOST
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: postgres-config
              key: POSTGRESURL
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: abcbank-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: abcbank
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8084
      targetPort: 8084
      nodePort: 30102
```

applicatio.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://${POSTGRES_HOST}/${POSTGRES_DB}
spring.datasource.username=${POSTGRES_USER}
spring.datasource.password=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
```

Run without any DB exception

Comment: The `postgres-service` is looking for a Pod with a label `tier: database`, but the Deployment's Pod spec doesn't include this label.